# Do I need to use threads in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running a Spark application which runs two separate Hive select queries via Spark SQL and then writes the results of each to a DB.

Note that I need to do a DB upsert, so can't use built-in Spark JDBC.

The code so far is something like this:

```
res1 = spark.sql(query1).collect()
res2 = spark.sql(query2).collect()
res1.foreach(lambda row: updateTable1(row))
res2.foreach(lambda row: updateTable2(row))
```

Since `collect()` is an action, I'm assuming that `res1` blocks and the operation for `res2` doesn't start until it's finished. I'm running on a cluster with two worker nodes, so is there any benefit to launching both `spark.sql()` commands in separate threads or is Spark smart enough to optimise everything for me?

Comment: are you really running a single SQL update? Why not writing the Dataframe directly to JDBC database instead of fetching to driver first and then doing those weird single update requests?

Comment: @UninformedUser I need to do an upsert, not an insert. There's no way to do that directly from the dataframe as far as I know. There will only be a maximum of 5 rows returned anyway.

Comment: I'm not worried about the final DB for now. I'm wondering if multi-threading will make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Below example is in **Scala** you should easily able to convert it into **PySpark**.

> Note : You will also need to combine *updateTable1* and *updateTable2*
>   to a common func *updateTable*

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val query1 = "select * from table1";
    val query2 = "select * from table2";
    val queries = Map(query1 -> "table1", query2 -> "table2")
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    spark.sparkContext.parallelize(queries.keys.toSeq).foreach(query => {
      val res = spark.sql(query).collect()
      updateTable(res, queries.get(query))
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use threads, just make sure that cluster have enough resources to process both tasks at the same time. Below is basic example

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def run(rdd, func):
    def delay(x):
        time.sleep(2)
        return func(x)
    return rdd.map(delay).sum()


rdd = sc.parallelize(range(1000), int(sc.defaultParallelism / 2))

t1 = Thread(target=run, args=(rdd, lambda x: x * 4))
t2  = Thread(target=run, args=(rdd, lambda x: x + 2))
t1.start(); t2.start()
```

An important reminder is to set set('spark.scheduler.mode','FAIR') in the sparkContext.